# WCF callback channel abort exception

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I implemented publisher-subscriber mechanism with WCF.

this is how I subscribe for callbacks :

```
public delegate void AsyncResponseEventHandler(AsyncResponse asyncResponse); 
public static event AsyncResponseEventHandler AsyncResponseEvent;       
public static IMyEvents Subscriber;        
public  void SubscribeEvent()        
{            
Subscriber = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyEvents>();            
AsyncResponseEvent += new AsyncResponseEventHandler (Subscriber.AsyncResponseCallBack);        
}         
public static void RaiseAsyncResponse(AsyncResponse asyncResponse)    
{         
   try 
           {                
        AsyncResponseEvent.Invoke(asyncResponse);
           }            
catch (Exception ex)  {throw;}    
}
```

and also this is the MySubscriber Class code:

```
     public class MySubscriber : IMyEvents
    {


 public void AsyncResponseCallBack(AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
        {

            AsyncResponseEventArgs e = new AsyncResponseEventArgs()
            {
                Response = asyncResponse
            };
            OnAsyncResponseReceived(this, e);

        }
    }
```

I use RaiseAsyncResponse method to raise callback to client ,

when service host is windows service and I start the service and I start debugging , everything works fine for the first time , but when I stop the client application and restart debugging with out restarting the windows service , I face the exception: The communication object, `System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel`, cannot be used for communication because it has been Abort ...

why the callback channel is aborted?
please help me out ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "but when I stop the client application" is the answer. Soon as you stop the client application, System.ServiceModel will release the hold on the channel. You can not send data from the service to client, or vice versa if you kill the service or the client.

Comment: thanks for the answer ... so my problem is based on how nettcpbinding works for callbacks , how can I implement duplex message pattern that I won't have to restart the service if I restart the client ?

Comment: First, you can always get the callback channel for the client anytime they call a function. Otherwise, you will need to store the callback channel, probably in a dictionary. Then, when the client starts up it should make a service call to "register" it's callback channel. Then the service can use it whenever it wants. In that service call, subscribe to the ChannelClosed event, and when the client disconnects remove the channel. When you restart the client, it should call the service again to register its callback.